# Rails 5: update_attributes with unique constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to call a `find_or_initialize_by` in a controller like so:

```
@lead = Lead.find_or_initialize_by(external_id: lead['external_id'])
@lead.update_attributes(lead)
```

That's all well and good, but my problem is that `lead` can and should have some information in it that has unique constraints on my model:

```
validates :address, uniqueness: { scope: [:address, :city, :state, :zip] }
validates :voter_id, uniqueness: true
validates :external_id, uniqueness: true
validates :email, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true, allow_nil: true
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :source, :status
```

So, when a lead already exists in the database, `update_attributes` fails because the hash contains the same information the record already did (coupled with a non-unique difference):

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Address has already been taken, Voter has already been taken, External has already been taken):
```

How can I pass this hash and have Rails save it regardless of whether it's new (made by `initialize_by`) or existing (made by `find`) while maintaining all that validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, [`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes) calls [`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes), which assigns the given attributes and overwrites existing values if they are different. But if the same value has been assigned before, this attribute is not considered changed and therefore will not be included in an updated query.

If everything is as it should be, your uniqueness validations should not fail at all - neither with a new nor an existing record. I would assume, there is some other quirk (which is not visible in the provided information about your context) causing these errors and would advise against simply disabling validation.

Comment: That is *super useful* to know, thank-you. I guess I should see if there's another quirk that might be causing the lead to be initialized instead of found.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5 use [update_attribute](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) instead of [update_attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update).

It updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure.

**Note**: `update_attribute` updates only one attribute at a time from the code given in question, I think it will work for you.

If this method doesn't suit you, you can also use `.update_columns` [found here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns).

Comment: That'd be useful if I was only updating one, or if I list them all out (neither solution is ideal for me). Thanks though.

Comment: Apparently you can try `update_columns`. This skips validations and callbacks as well.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns

Comment: `update_columns` won't work on new records. I think I'll have to write a method with `persisted?` or something to get around this.

Comment: what do you mean new records? On new records you can explicitly skip validations if you need to.

Comment: I'm using `find_or_initialize_by`, so records can be either new or existing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@lead = Lead.find_or_initialize_by(external_id: lead['external_id'])
@lead.attributes = lead
@lead.save(validate: false)
```

This should do the trick
Not sure why you would go around your validations, this will bite you later.

Api links:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save